# GAE local - PHP-CGI Fatal Error Unable to write base address

Tags: php, windows, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

After a clean install of Google cloud SDK, I try to test HelloWorld project without success.

for installation, I follow this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart

My dev env. is on windows 10 x64

```
Current Cloud SDK version is: 209.0.0
| gRPC python library          |      1.9.1 |  
| gcloud app PHP Extensions    | 2017.09.15 | 
| gcloud app Python Extensions |     1.9.73 |
```

But when i go on helloworld folder and run this command :

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

I have this log with this error :

```
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:55,812 devappserver2.py:178] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:57,565 api_server.py:274] Starting API server at: http://localhost:59911
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:57,661 dispatcher.py:270] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:57,673 admin_server.py:152] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2018-07-24 17:27:58,806 module.py:1676] "C:\Dev\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86\php-cgi.exe -v" returned an error [-2]
Tue Jul 24 17:27:58 2018 (14128): Fatal Error Unable to write base address

INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:59,680 shutdown.py:50] Shutting down.
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:59,681 stub_util.py:357] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2018-07-24 17:27:59,684 stub_util.py:360] Saving search indexes
```

when i run this command, i have no problem :

```
"C:\Dev\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\php-5.5-Win32-VC11-x86\php-cgi.exe" -v

PHP 5.5.26 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Nov  9 2015 01:15:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

So why i have this error with SDK command ?